# Using a CGImageDestination to take data from an NSImage and write BMP data to a NSData, but I end up missing my alpha channel

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, bitmap, core-graphics

I'm trying to take data from an `NSImage` and write it out as 32-bit BMP data with RGBA (8 bits per channel) in an `NSData` object. Here's my code:

```
- (NSData *)dataRepresentation {
    NSImage *textureImage = self.textureImage;
    NSSize size = [textureImage size];
    NSImageRep *imageRep = [[textureImage representations] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height);

    CGImageRef outputImage = [imageRep CGImageForProposedRect:&rect context:NULL hints:nil];
    CFMutableDataRef textureData = CFDataCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, size.width*size.height*4+54);
    CGImageDestinationRef imageDestination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData(textureData, kUTTypeBMP, 1, NULL);

    CFStringRef keys[1] = {kCGImagePropertyHasAlpha};
    CFBooleanRef values[1] = {kCFBooleanTrue};
    CFDictionaryRef options = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const void **)keys, (const void **)values, 1, NULL, NULL);

    CGImageDestinationAddImage(imageDestination, outputImage, options);
    CFRelease(options);
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(imageDestination);
    CFRelease(imageDestination);
    return (NSData *)CFBridgingRelease(textureData);
}
```

The data that results is missing the alpha channel. It correctly has 8 bits per component, but is missing the alpha channel altogether. I thought that the options dictionary with the `kCGImagePropertyHasAlpha` property would fix it but it hasn't. I'm not sure this is really the right approach anyway, can someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: You might want to look through the representations array for the NSBitmapImageRep with the highest pixel count (`pixelsWide * pixelsHigh`), or use `bestRepresentationForRect:context:hints:`, rather than assuming that the very first representation is and will always be the one you want. Alternatively, don't look for a rep at all, and send your `CGImageForProposedRect:context:hints:` message directly to the image.